# What is this constructor doing? new MailAddress[0]

Tags: c#, mailaddress

I know how to use MailAddress like this:
`new MailAddress("someone@foo.com")`

But what is this I'm seeing:
`new MailAddress[0]` - how is this used and when is it ok to use? I don't see anything about this in the docs on MSDN.

Comment: `new MailAddress[0]` creates an array of `MailAddress`es of 0 size (i.e. no elements). You can use it whenever you want. It's not specific to the `MailAddress` type.

Comment: Ah ok. And is this just used to satisfy type requirements when calling a given method?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing its use in context, but more than likely, yes.

Comment: It's usually used when you need to pass in an empty collection, though `Enumerable.Empty<MailAddress>()` would be the preferred way to do it, assuming the method needs a sequence rather than an array.

Comment: its a way to pass in an empty array to a function that requires an array

Comment: Note that it is considered a very poor programming practice to pass `null` in when what you mean is "a collection that happens to be empty".  Whoever wrote this code should be given points for not passing null, but could also have clarified the code by saying why it is that they're passing in an empty collection.

Comment: awesome thanks, makes sense now

Comment: @EricLippert Just wondering, why something like [`EmptyArray.Value`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8a9692baba002fe6.html) was not made public? It replicated many time in .NET Framework itself: [1](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/09bbfaa1f07d0c51.html), [2](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/61f6a8d9f0c40f6e.html), [3](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/84d671b41038f83d.html), [4](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/106534f51ac82633.html).

Comment: @PetSerAl: There's no need to supply a reason for *not* doing a trivial feature that any developer can do themselves. Such a feature would add almost no value, but add significant costs: design, testing, documentation, and so on.

Comment: @EricLippert - I would remove the "testing" part or are you saying that the .NET devs only test stuff thats public? ;)

Comment: @EricLippert Point is to reduce amount of unique empty array instances, that is why them cached in the first place instead of using `new T[0]` everywhere. Sure it is trivial to make such cache per assembly. But I do not see any trivial way to make it per `AppDomain`. Yes, anyone can create assembly with public empty array cache, but no one will use it unless it is part of core library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all the comments above.... the main difference is

```
mailAddress mA = new mailAddress();
```

mA object is initialized by calling default constructor.

```
mailAddress[] mA1 = new mailAddress[0];
```

In this case, no object is initialized, it is just declaration of array of objects. No constructor calls.

Comment: @Naidu That explains why it's valid to construct an array of size zero.  Not why it's valid to access the first element of an array with zero items in it.  Feel free to run the code yourself if you want to see it for yourself.

Comment: I was totally blinded with construction.....and thought some kind of optimization is working..... Thanks you @Sefe